# $.ajax and return value in JQUERY

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there an example for the $.ajax() that returns values from a webservice or should I use $.ajaxSetup() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gabriel Hurley has given the right answer, I just want to elaborate a bit.  I like to use the ajax function, rather than get or post as I find it more readable and you can react to the different results of the ajax call.

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   dataType: "html"
   url: "services/addUser",
   data: "{name:'Jo', email:'an@ddress.com'}",
   success: function(result){
     //It worked!
   },
   error: function(err) {
     //The ajax call didn't work
     alert("It didn't work: " + err);
   }
 });
```

Comment: How do i get an integer value. my parseInt(result) is not invoked and no error

Comment: If it's not getting called you need to check where the script is failing so debug it with firebug/visual studio.  If you wanna give some more detail I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1):

The [jQuery ajax docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) have a whole tab of examples.

Particularly, you can look at the success callback in the options tab to see the appropriate syntax for getting the data that's returned.